# MinGW on Cygwin. Some issues on linking the GNU Scientific Library

Tags: c++, cygwin, mingw, static-linking, gsl

I have a couple of issues when linking the GNU Scientific Library with MinGW on Cygwin. Let me explain the situation.

I have installed both MinGW and GSL from the Cygwin setup utility. 
The path `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/` contains:

```
gsl-config           libgfortran-3.dll                 libssp-0.dll
libatomic-1.dll      libgomp-1.dll                     libstdc++-6.dll
libblas.dll          libgomp-plugin-host_nonshm-1.dll  libvtv_stubs-0.dll
libcblas.dll         libgsl-19.dll                     libvtv-0.dll
libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll  libquadmath-0.dll                 libwinpthread-1.dll
```

The path `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/`contains all the GSL headers.

The path `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/`contains, among many other libraries, the files `libgsl.dll.a` and `libgslcblas.dll.a`

If I compile using

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++11 -s someGSLapp.cpp -lgsl -static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -lpthread -lm
```

it compiles without any problem, and the executable can be run provided `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/` is properly added to PATH environment variable.

Let me point out the first strange issue. If I do not set the PATH variable, in order to run my program, I have to copy all files in `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/` into the path where my executable is located. Be careful, ALL files, not only the GSL DLLs. This is strange, because other libraries are linked statically. Indeed, I have other programs that do not use GSL, and when I compile them statically linking the standard library in the same way as I do for my someGSLapp above, they can be run without setting PATH, nor copying any DLLs.

The second issue happens when I try to statically link the GSL. If I try:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++11 -s someGSLapp.cpp -static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -lpthread -lm -lgsl
```

the GNU linker returns the error `cannot find -lgsl`. I tried to add

```
-I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/
-L/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/
```

but it does not change anything, I still get the same error.

So, concerning the first issue, could anyone explain why I need to copy ALL the DLLs? My tentative explanation is that the GSL DLL needs the others, but I cannot understand why even the fortran DLL is needed.

Concerning the second issue, could anyone tell me how to link the GSL statically?

UPDATE on the second issue

If I link statically using

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++11 -s someGSLapp.cpp -static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -lpthread -lm -lgsl.dll
```

I do not get the error `cannot find -lgsl` anymore, compilation and linking terminate without any error or warning, but the executable still do not run if I do not set PATH or copy all the DLLs as seen above. It seems that static linking is not working for the GSL.

Comment: Do you have static libraries? You mentioned you have `libgsl.dll.a`, what about `libgsl.a`?

Comment: @ssbssa I don't have it. I assumed that libgsl.dll.a were the right library file since its extension is .a. Apparently it is not possible to install ligsl.a from any cywin package. I will try to install GSL manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. It seems that precompiled GSL packages currently available through the Cygwin setup utility does not allow to statically link the library. Indeed, as noticed by @ssbssa in a comment, they do not install libgsl.a

This is what I did. First I completely removed all GSL packages previously installed. From the main GSL repository ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/ I downloaded the latest version of the library into a local path.

GNU make has to be already installed. I used

```
./configure CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc --prefix=/usr/gsl/mingw64/
```

CC sets the compiler to be used. --prefix sets the path the library will be installed into. Then I called `make` and, as soon it finished compiling, `make install`.

Since I need to compile programs also for 32 bit systems, I called `make clean` to start a new installation, then I set

```
./configure CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc --prefix=/usr/gsl/mingw32/
```

and then again `make` and `make install`. Now I can cross-compile programs using GSL for both 32 and 64 bits, and I can statically link the library simply adding the `-static` flag

Answer (score 1):

Try adding -static. Linking a DLL might not generate a static dependency on the library without the according flag, if at all. 
Also linking stdc++ is usually not needed. (as is the -W,.. If -static is used.

Comment: I've tried, but I get exactly the same outcome described in my UPDATE above